# Django way to represent languages of users

Tags: python, django

I have the Follower class

```
class Follower(models.Model):
    language = models.ManyToManyField(
        "instagram_data.Language", verbose_name=_("language_code_name"), blank=True)
```

and the Lang class:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    code_name = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code_name
```

Where looking for negative value e.g **user_langugae != 'ar** I get the following lookup:

```
SELECT * FROM "instagram_data_follower" WHERE NOT ("instagram_data_follower"."id" IN (SELECT U1."follower_id" FROM "instagram_data_follower_language" U1 INNER JOIN "instagram_data_language" U2 ON (U1."language_id" = U2."id") WHERE U2."code_name" = ar)))
```

Which takes so longggggg over 20 minute sometimes.
Lookup for equal is much faster.

I think I need to redesign the schema so languages will be kind of bitmap.
Can you suggest a better way to look up on negative condition for one to many field  ?

Most of my lookups are **user_langugae != 'ar** AND **user_langugae == 'he'**

I Saw this:
https://github.com/disqus/django-bitfield
btw

Comment: Have you run the query through your database's `EXPLAIN` functionality?

Comment: Also, shouldn't `code_name` be `unique=True` and not nullable?

Comment: correct unique true. will that make lookups faster IYO?

Comment: It will, since it causes the field to be an unique index.

Comment: So I added , unique=True but why should I remove NULL ? btw I see every code_name has it own id so it is unique already ritght ?

Comment: If you think about your data model, is it possible for a language to not have a code name? If not, remove `blank=True, null=True`.